# Java - Adding a new line every n characters without breaking apart the word

Tags: java

So I have been trying to get a user inputted string to have a newline every n amount of characters. What I have found is a basically what I have written, I am pretty new to Java(Python has a function to .fill but I cant figure this out in Java) and cant seem to get my string to not break words apart. I set the program to "\n" every 10 characters but then it breaks some words right in the middle... I want it to take that word and move it to the next line if it will not fit into the 10 character limit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your text: ");
        String newString = scan.nextLine();
        newString = newString.replaceAll(".{10}",  "$0\n");
        System.out.println(newString);
```

/** Second Method, still cuts the words off...

```
    StringBuilder builtString = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while ((i= builtString.indexOf(newString, i + 10)) != -1) {
            builtString.replace(i, i+1, "\n");
        
        }
        System.out.println(builtString);
        */
    
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
}
```

Words are broken apart :(

Output:

```
This is a 
test and i
t doesnt s
eem to be 
working pr
operly.
```

In Python I got this output which was what I wanted, but Java doesn't seem to have a textwrap function that's "easy" like Python's or at least I haven't figured it out yet.
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzYu0.png)

Comment: It will be easy to understand your question, when you put expected output as well with input

Comment: What if a word is longer than 10 characters?  Do you want to split it, allow it, or hyphenate it?

Comment: One way to break at word boundries to to start at the maximum (ten letters), and search backwards for a space. If you can't find one, then you have to deal with @k2col 's situation.

Comment: I edited my original post and posted a picture of what the "desired output" is, I got it working in python but I am learning Java and there doesn't seem to be a "textwrap fill" function.

And yes you guys do have a good point...if the word is longer then 10 then it will throw an error, my main goal for this was to try to better understand how to separate strings by lines and keep the original word from breaking apart.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This is a test and it doesnt seem to be working properly.";
    String[] works = text.split(" "); // get list of works
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String work : works) {
        if (line.length() + work.length() > 10) { //add line to result if it full
            result.append(line).append("\n");
            line = new StringBuilder(); //reset line is empty
        }
        line.append(work).append(" ");
    }
    result.append(line);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: although this may work, it would be better to add some plain text explanation of what's going on, not just a bit of code. OP and others will learn much more if they understand your code, instead of just copying it.

Comment: So this works PERFECTLY, now I just have to break down the code piece by piece because I want to understand it, rather than copy/paste! I appreciate it though as your code definitely made my problem solvable.